# how to go another view onclick LazyVGrid GridItem in swiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I using LazyVGrid which is dynamically populated. I want to another page on click grid item.

Here is grid image..

[image]

I have three view.When I click Funtransfer GridItem, it navigate **FundtransferView**. If I click on **top up**  GridItem, it goes to **TopupView**

Here is the code of generate gridview

```
  LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(arrayRes.indices) { index in
                            Group{
                                VStack{
                                    Image("\((arrayRes[index]["icon"]) as! String)")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                    Text("\((arrayRes[index]["displayValue"]) as! String)")
                                        .padding(.top,5)
                                        .padding(.bottom,5)
                                    //.padding(.bottom,10)
                                }.padding(.top,5)
                                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 60)
                                // .padding()
                                
                            }.listRowBackground(backgroundColor)
                                .padding(5)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .padding([.top, .horizontal])
                            //.shadow(color: .blue, radius: 5)
                                .shadow(color: Color.blue.opacity(0.2), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 2)
                                .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                                    
                                   getGridItem(index: index)
                                    
                                })
                        }
                    }
```

Here is the function where i get grid item index & separate view to navigate.
Bellow g**etGridItem function how to go to another page?**

```
func getGridItem(index:Int){

 var softcode = ((arrayRes[index]["softcode"]) as! String)
    if("FundTransfer" == softcode){

        //Navigate to fund transfer view

    }else if("MYB_BKASH" == softcode){

        //Navigate to fund top up view
    }
    
}
```

Here is two destinaiton view:

```
        struct FundtransferView: View {
            var body: some View {
                Text("Hello, FundtransferView")
            }
        }


       struct TopupView: View {
            var body: some View {
                Text("Hello, TopupView!")
            }
        }
```

From the getGridItem function, how to navigate FundtransferView & TopupView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an example:

[image]

```
struct DetailView: View {

var index: Int

var body: some View {
    
    if index == 0 {
        FundtransferView()
    }
    else {
        TopupView()
    }
}

struct FundtransferView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, FundtransferView")
    }
}

struct TopupView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Hello, TopupView!")
        }
    }
}

struct ItemView: View {

var image: String

var body: some View {
    Group{
        VStack{
            Image(systemName: image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            Text(image)
                .padding(.top,5)
                .padding(.bottom,5)
            //.padding(.bottom,10)
        }.padding(.top,5)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 60)
        // .padding()
    }.listRowBackground(Color.black)
        .padding(5)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding([.top, .horizontal])
    //.shadow(color: .blue, radius: 5)
        .shadow(color: Color.blue.opacity(0.2), radius: 4, x: 0, y: 2)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    
@State var index: Int = 0
@State var arrayRes: [String] = ["person","heart"]

let columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))]


var body: some View {
    
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(arrayRes.indices) { index in
            NavigationLink(destination:
                DetailView(index: index)
            ) {
                ItemView(image:arrayRes[index])
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```